# I installed ROS melodic for my 18.04 Unbuntu. But I couldnt launch gazebo with the gazebo command

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After I typed gazebo and entered, this happened:

```
gazebo: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgazebo_common.so.9: undefined symbol: _ZN8ignition10fuel_tools12ClientConfig12SetUserAgentERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327766/i-installed-ros-melodic-for-my-18.04-unbuntu.-but-i-couldnt-launch-gazebo-with-the-gazebo-command./) by [Sy Anh](https://answers.ros.org/users/43986/sy-anh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-07-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-07-05**:
Looks similar to https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2448/problem-running-gazebo7 . Try upgrading the libignition-math2 package as suggested on that ticket.

**Comment by [Sy Anh](https://answers.ros.org/users/43986/sy-anh/) on 2019-07-05**:
Unfortunately, it was very different. Thanks for your help

**Comment by [drhombus](https://answers.ros.org/users/45336/drhombus/) on 2019-09-02**:
what ended up fixing it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Upgrading the libraries worked for me `sudo apt upgrade libignition-math2`

---

Originally posted by [cambel07](https://answers.ros.org/users/50158/cambel07/) with karma: 92 on 2019-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SwapUNaph](https://answers.ros.org/users/56393/swapunaph/) on 2020-07-03**:
I get this when I upgrade `libignition-math2`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree    
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libignition-math2
```